# How to UPDATE NULL values by MAX()+1?

Tags: mysql, update, max

I want to assign values to null cells of a column as

```
UPDATE table 1
SET number = MAX(number) + 1
WHERE number IS NULL
```

but mysql return error `Invalid use of group function`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15522621

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want - if the `max(number)` in the whole table is say, 27 - to update  all the rows with NULL, to 28.

You need a subquery or a derived table to first find this max and then join back to the table:

```
UPDATE tableX AS t
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT MAX(number) AS max_number
      FROM tableX
    ) AS m
SET t.number = m.max_number + 1
WHERE t.number IS NULL ;
```